# [META] BrewAdvice.com Feedback?

Tags: meta

#### Hello All,

If you've found your way here you may know a site admin (myself or PJ). We'd like to thank you for testing and contributing to our experiment. The content developing here has exceeded any expectations we had, and has already helped me with my brewing.

To keep moving forward, we'd like to ask for any feedback you may have about the site.
Confused about functionality? Hate the style? Ideas for tags? Topics? Like badges? etc.

**Note:**
We are limited in terms of *some* functionality at this point, as we are operating on top of a platform we don't entirely control. Though, if there is enough interest in additional (or less) functionality, we may be able to make a change.

<strike>(Don't worry, we're getting a new logo shortly.)</strike>

Answer (score 2):

This is annoying.     * new users can only post answers every 3 minutes; try again later.

Answer (score 2):

I really like the points and badges system. I would like to be able to comment right away though. The up/down arrows for voting was not initially clear.

Comment: Sadly we don't have any control over the rep rules. We are considering rewriting the software in php so we have total control. Any ideas on how to make the voting more clear?

Comment: I wouldn't mess with it.  This system works really well for StackOverflow.com with thousands of users.  Use the software without modification for a few months to get an appreciation for how good it is.

The FAQ is a good place to explain how voting works. A better "how this site works" document would go a long way.

Answer (score 2):

If I may make a suggestion, you need to clean out some of the less well thought out questions and duplicate questions.  There are only five users who can actually downvote right now and none of them are doing it.

The site will suffer if some of these duplicate or recipe questions stay on the front page for as long as they have. I don't want to single out any question, but some of these questions are crap and should simply be deleted for the good of the site.  It looking a little static and I think its because many of these questions are simply poor.

Just a suggestion that might help get things moving, since you don't really have enough people who can effectively downvote.

Comment: You're a little closer now. The community will sort it out in time. I think we are at a time when we should encourage participation and be very judicial with the negative points.

Answer (score 1):

A good "how this site works" document explaining favoriting and the arrows for both questions and answers.

Comment: With screenshots

Comment: We can do something like that on the blog. The FAQs (http://brewadvice.com/faq) don't get into "how" to vote, but do explain a little about voting.

Comment: You can't edit the FAQ?

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if these [Meta] questions should be community wikis.
Just a thought. As they don't contribute to reputation right???

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with the site "chronometer".  I was recently looking at my history and there are gaps in days where I know I logged in.  I wonder if my 12AM is not the sites 12AM.  So where I think I logged in on a different day the site thinks I logged in on the say day.  Wierd.

Comment: There's a good chance that the server time isn't the same as your time. As a test, it is now 9:38am MST on 2/10/10.

Comment: When I look at my messages I see "Showing 2010-02-11 to 2010-02-11 ; current time is 2010-02-11 16:16:44 UTC". Maybe it runs on GMT/UTC